# Align dropdown items to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have placed checkboxes within a dropdown using bootstrap, however they are all center aligned. I would like to left align the dropdown items. Here's the code

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <label class="dropdown-item-left"><input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="result[]">AAAAA</label>
 
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="result[]">BBBBBBBBBB</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="result[]">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</label>
    
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="result[]">DDDDDDDDD</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="result[]">EEEEEEEE</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I tried using text-align: left, align-self, etc using a separate css file, but it did not work.

Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is just html file ... Simplest way to use flexbox to order it in right way.
Check the snippet

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
  
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <label class="dropdown-item-left"><input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="result[]">AAAAA</label>
 
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="result[]">BBBBBBBBBB</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="result[]">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</label>
    
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="result[]">DDDDDDDDD</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="result[]">EEEEEEEE</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this bro but it does not work and it also takes away the toggle feature, displaying it below the button.

Comment: Add your css file, I can check it

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `dropdown-item-left` with `dropdown-item`. Check out this code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
        <label class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="result[]">AAAAA</input>
        </label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="result[]">BBBBBBBBBB</input>
        </label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="result[]">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</input>
        </label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="result[]">DDDDDDDDD</input>
        </label>
        <label class="dropdown-item">
            <input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="result[]">EEEEEEEE</input>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

I added the ending  tags. And here is the end-result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Input elements default behavior is `display: inline` so to align button and dropdown menu content vertically I added below CSS code to `dropdown-item-left .dropdown-item` classes and `form1` id.

Also I added some functionality to your button. Now it can hide and display menu.

```js
function handleClick() {
  var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
  if(form1.style.display === "none") {
    form1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    form1.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-item-left, .dropdown-item {
  display: block;
}

#form1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
          type="button"         
          id="dropdownMenuButton2" 
          data-toggle="dropdown" 
          aria-haspopup="true" 
          aria-expanded="false"
          onClick="handleClick();">
          Dropdown button
  </button>
  
  <form id="form1" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton2">
    <label class="dropdown-item-left"><input type="checkbox" id="f1" name="result[]">AAAAA</label>
 
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f2" name="result[]">BBBBBBBBBB</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f3" name="result[]">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</label>
    
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f4" name="result[]">DDDDDDDDD</label>

    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="f5" name="result[]">EEEEEEEE</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you bro. This helped.